# How to use htaccess to flip from https to http

Tags: .htaccess, https

Well I have a site that uses relative paths for all the URLs.  I just added a shopping cart so the two or three checkout pages are using HTTPS instead of HTTP.  My problem is that a user is mid way through checkout and clicks a link on the navigation or whatever it seems them to that page *with* HTTPS when it is a page that doesn't require it (and it some cases can't handle it because of external files e.g. GoogleMaps.js)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually surprised myself and hacked something together.  Reroutes everything that isn't www.domain.com/checkout

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(/checkout)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 2):

you can try doing something like

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^(80|8080)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(checkout|order|etc)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$         http://yoururl$1
```

I'm not sure if it works because I didn't test it, but you could use the ideea of testing for {SERVER_PORT}. Hope it helps

Comment: You answered this while I was typing my answer.  I like yours better  though!

Comment: it's pretty much the same thing.
actually, using %{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} like you did is more elegant :)

Comment: Better not to rely on port numbers. Check if HTTPS is on (or off, if you want to force it on).

Comment: Yeah. Scott is probably right. I used port because I didn't know about %{HTTPS}.

Comment: Agreed, %{HTTPS} is the thing to use here.

Answer (score 0):

You don’t need the additional `RewriteCond` directive to exclude `/checkout/…`:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule !^checkout(/|$) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```